# What is Device initializer APIs android?

Tags: android

In the [Android M changes document](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-afw) they says

> Device initializer APIs which existed in the Android 6.0 (API level 23) are now removed.

what is the `Device initializer APIs` ?

Answer (score 0):

Its a component of enterprise provisioning.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver.html